# Vercel build fails without logs

Tags: logging, next.js, build, vercel, next.js13

I'm trying to build my NextJs 13.5.4 application on Vercel but the build always fails. The only log I get is this:

```
[10:48:44.650] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
[10:48:44.745] Cloning github.com/secret/secret(Branch: master, Commit: b350bac)
[10:48:45.064] Cloning completed: 317.92ms
[10:48:45.103] Previous build cache not available
[10:48:45.254] Running "vercel build"
[10:48:45.693] Vercel CLI 32.4.1
[10:48:46.028] Installing dependencies...
[10:49:08.196] 
[10:49:08.196] added 442 packages in 22s
[10:49:08.197] 
[10:49:08.197] 128 packages are looking for funding
[10:49:08.197]   run `npm fund` for details
[10:49:08.225] Detected Next.js version: 13.5.4
```

Locally, `next build` runs successfully. I also tried `vercel build` locally but due to a lack of admin permission on my work laptop, the command has some problems with symlinks later on which obviously hasn't anything to do with the situation on Vercel.

Since I don't get any logs on Vercel, I'm stuck.  Any idea what I can try?